# Color polygons using SQL Database based Rules in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, sql

I want the rules to be applied according to values in a database. Is it possible to include external database information that is not in the shapefile?

In spoken words the original rule is "Color all vectors where the property:order07 is less than value:04000 with the color #ffeecc"

and I want to change it into something like "Color the vectors where the property:fromDatabase xy: is value:xxyy with the color #xxxxxx"

Comment: I hope we can do it. Look at some tutorials regarding POSTGIS + SLD.